# How to drop ArcSDE connection using Python scripting?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I want to be able to control connections to ArcSDE via python. Here is my script so far using ESRI's example.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"SDEConnection" 
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print str(fcList) + "\n"
env.workspace = "" 
arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache(r"SDEConnection")
print arcpy.GetMessages() + "\n"
```

But this isnt working .. it crashes my Python window :(

Comment: Where did you get the sample from?  Providing a link would be helpful.

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000000m000000

Comment: And i just noticed the syntax in that site says ClearWorkspaceCache_management.. but in the example it doesnt.. hmm im going to try with the 'management' on the end now.. i will let you know what the outcome is

Comment: Oh, it seems it is all ESRI's fault! In their example on the helpdesk they have got the syntax wrong. Excluding the word 'management' from the end of 'ClearWorkspaceCache'

I corrected my script to read
> arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management(r"SDEConnection")

Comment: @Kam- Since you answered your own question, please put the above comment into the answer area and, in a couple of days, you should be able to mark your question as accepted.  I would suggest updating your code with the corrected syntax.

Comment: It appears that ESRI have corrected the code in the 10.1 example: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000000m000000

Answer (score 3):

According to the [updated help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000000m000000), you need to use `arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()`

You can use the following code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "c:/connectionFiles/Connection to gpserver.sde"
arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()
```

This answer has been derived from [OP's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33429/how-to-drop-arcsde-connection-using-python-scripting#comment44872_33429) on the question.